# Using Lasso for non-linear regression (Python)

Tags: python, non-linear-regression, lasso-regression

I have a set of independent data points X, and a set of dependent points Y, and I would like to find a model of the form:

(a<sub>0</sub>+a<sub>1</sub>*x<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>2</sub>*x<sub>2</sub>+...+a<sub>m</sub>*x<sub>m</sub>)*(a<sub>m+1</sub>*x<sub>m+1</sub>+a<sub>m+2</sub>*x<sub>m+2</sub>)

I know I can use scipy's curve_fit, but to avoid overfitting, I want to use Lasso for the linear part (i.e. the part in the first set of parenthesis).

Is there a simple way of doing that in Python?

Comment: Add some example data and info about the size of the data fitted in your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit a lasso regressor to the whole lot, multiplying out your brackets giving you 2m+2 coefficients. Then by performing a change of variables you can make this a linear regression problem again.

See this link for more details:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression

Comment: You're right, the function I gave wasn't a very good example. I edited the question to have an actual non-linear function for which I can't use your trick. thanks :)

Comment: The problem is that the Lasso will find the optimum parameters assuming that the stuff in the second brackets isn't there. You could still multiply out the brackets now giving you 2m+2 variables. The trickier part is that you won't have a constant so you will have to force the constant to be zero in the lasso.

Comment: I was hoping there was an existing solution that combines curve_fit and lasso (which receives a function as an input like curve_fit, but penalizes coefficients like lasso), but I guess I'll need to take a different approach.
Thanks for you're help!

Comment: Ok. Perhaps then you could fit the lasso as I suggested first and then use curve_fit on the reduced set of variables afterwards. Experiment though because the original lasso may prove to be better than curve_fit anyway.

Comment: I did some reading and found a method to generalize your solution to any polynomial fitting. Using this your solution fits my problem, so if you'd like to add it I'd mark your answer as a solution (if you don't, I'll just post it as a second answer)
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression
thanks for your help!